# Creating a custom TI 84 plus graphing calculator Operating System (OS)

Tags: assembly, operating-system, calculator, texas-instruments, ti-basic

I am starting a project in which I will be making a new/editing the standard TI 84 Plus Calculator OS. I am planning on only changing a few things that slow it down and are not neccesarry for me. (EX: Asymptote checking while graphing, "PrettyPrint" or "MathPrint" options) I would also like to add a simple password protection screen for whenever I have turned off my Calculator to prevent data theft.

I am familiar with "Basic Programming". I am very skilled in TI Basic (Calculator Programming) and have a bit of programming experience in Java and ASM, although the only assembly code I have used is on TI 84 Plus Graphing Calculators... I am looking for some more info as well as the way I should go about making this new OS.

---

Useful Links:

- [TI Calc.org](http://www.ticalc.org/)
- [TI Calc OS Programs](http://www.ticalc.org/pub/83plus/os/)
- [TI Basic Dev](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/)

More TI Calc stuff from another cool site: [Manual link](http://www.teshack.com/tag/ticalculators)

- [SmileyOS](http://www.ticalc.org/pub/83plus/os/smileyos.zip) - This is one simple custom OS I have seen before, so I do know it is possible to do something similar to what I am describing.

---

I am looking for someone who knows a bit more about this topic to give me some tips, and guide me in the right direction. I do want to be able to do some work on my own, so I am not asking anyone to do the work for me, simply help me out along the way giving advice.

Comment: SO is not for random "tips" (it's a QA thing, not a forum), but you can head over to a forum where actual experts on this subject hang out, such as Omnimaga or Cemetech. Also, the difference between editing the original OS and making a new one (that, I assume, has to be compatible?) is huge.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really know where this post should go, sorry about posting it here, i'll go ahead and close the thread and move it over to: www.omnimaga.org/index.php?topic=14309

Comment: Here's a new link to that thread: http://ourl.ca/16906

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell called MirageOS, by Detached Solutions.  It's versatile enough that you could likely write the features you want as applications which you can run, which would solve your problems much more easily.  Password protection is built in.